# Why is only one of my objects in my Realm Database showing up on my tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

```
if realm.objects(Accomp2.self).count > 0 {
            for acc in accompData {
                models.removeAll()
                if acc.month == date4 {
                    models.append(acc)
                    //print(models)
                    count += 1
                }
            }
        }
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].title
        let date = models[indexPath.row].date
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, YYYY"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formatter.string(from: date!)
        return cell
    }
```

In the first block of code, I add the objects that have the date from this month from the Realm Database to an array called models. When I print out models, I can see all the objects and their properties.
Then, in these two tableView functions, I return the number of objects in `models`, but the count only returns "1." I tried to use the count variable and return that instead, but it then gives me an error in the `cellForRowAt` function saying that those objects do not exist. I am not sure why I can only access one of the objects from `models` which I declare before the `viewDidLoad()` method as `var models = [Accomp2]()` Should I be using another tableView method, or is there a way to access all of the objects and create tableView cells for all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the `removeAll` clears the array every cycle leaving only the last item , you see all in console as you print them individually

```
  for acc in accompData {
            models.removeAll()
```

i guess it could be

```
 models.removeAll()
  for acc in accompData {
```

Comment: that worked! I didn't realize that line was within the array and not before it. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question was moving the models.removeAll() out of the array.

Comment: As of stackoverflow policy don't add a repetitive answer if there is already a similar working 1